# How to get all chrome content settings?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chromium

Google Chrome does not sync all content settings, specifically **Cookie rules**.
Meanwhile JavaScript settings sync fine.

I'm trying to query the list of all cookie blocking domains so I can sync them using my own storage through an extension. Wildcard patterns only work if TLD is specified.

```
chrome.contentSettings.cookies.get({
    primaryUrl: 'https://example.com' //---Not working '<all_urls>' or 'https://*/*"'
}, function (details) {
    console.log(details)
});
```

Could I possibly query **chrome://settings/content/cookies** as a web page directly from an extension?
Any other ideas?

Documentation for [Chrome content settings](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings) seems to support `'<all_urls>'` but it only works on 'set' not 'get'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the primaryUrl with a value like `http://*` or `https://*` or `http://somesite.com/` etc., and you then get the `details.setting`

Also note the delay I use before accessing the info at the end of the function below.

```
 function GetContentSettings(){

 var S='';

 chrome.contentSettings.cookies.get({primaryUrl:'http://*'},function(details){S+='Cookies : '+details.setting+'<br>';});
 chrome.contentSettings.images.get({primaryUrl:'http://*'},function(details){S+='Images : '+details.setting+'<br>';});
 chrome.contentSettings.javascript.get({primaryUrl:'http://*'},function(details){S+='JavaScript : '+details.setting+'<br>';});
 chrome.contentSettings.location.get({primaryUrl:'http://*'},function(details){S+='Location : '+details.setting+'<br>';});
 chrome.contentSettings.plugins.get({primaryUrl:'http://*'},function(details){S+='Plugins : '+details.setting+'<br>';});
 chrome.contentSettings.popups.get({primaryUrl:'http://*'},function(details){S+='Popups : '+details.setting+'<br>';});
 chrome.contentSettings.notifications.get({primaryUrl:'http://*'},function(details){S+='Notifications : '+details.setting+'<br>';});
 // chrome.contentSettings.fullscreen.get({primaryUrl:'http://*'},function(details){S+='Full Screen : '+details.setting+'<br>';});
 // chrome.contentSettings.mouselock.get({primaryUrl:'http://*'},function(details){S+='Mouse Lock : '+details.setting+'<br>';});
 chrome.contentSettings.microphone.get({primaryUrl:'http://*'},function(details){S+='Microphone : '+details.setting+'<br>';});
 chrome.contentSettings.camera.get({primaryUrl:'http://*'},function(details){S+='Camera : '+details.setting+'<br>';});
 chrome.contentSettings.unsandboxedPlugins.get({primaryUrl:'http://*'},function(details){S+='Unsandboxed Plugins : '+details.setting+'<br>';});
 chrome.contentSettings.automaticDownloads.get({primaryUrl:'http://*'},function(details){S+='Automatic Downloads : '+details.setting+'<br>';});

 setTimeout(function(){alert('Content Settings...<br><br>'+S);},1500);
 }
```

NB: I've commented out the two troublesome ones.

Comment: Thanks you!! i'll try it out soon and let you know

Comment: Not useful. E.g., cookies gets one answer, "allow", but I have some sites restricted to session only. How do I get a list of those black-listed sites?